# Deleted Unix and Grub partitions - can't boot into Windows anymore

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I get prompted with the grub rescue. The partition holding windows is intact. I also have access to another computer and a USB stick. Can I boot into Windows without losing my data?

Comment: Welcome, you can access your data with a live linux pendrive. It seems to me that the solution to your problem is to reinstall windows bootloader with a rescue windows tool. Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/623941/how-to-install-windows-bootloader-to-mbr)

Comment: Would it be safer to back up the critical data with a Linux pendrive before attempting to reinstall the bootloader?

Comment: @GeneralGravicius I think that would be advisable

Comment: Is a Linux pendrive able to read data from a Windows partition? And could you advise me with which Linux pendrive to go with?

Comment: @GeneralGravicius yes, in this case microsoft NTFS/FAT.

Comment: *" And could you advise me with which Linux pendrive to go with"*, any will work, let's say [Linux Mint xfce for example](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=283).

Comment: I forgot to mention the laptop I have access to right now is a Mac. Can I create the Linux pendrive with that?

Comment: I think yes, but I don't know the tools... I've never had a Mac in my hands ^^

Comment: [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: I managed to boot a live Ubuntu from a USB stick but I'm unsure what to do next. I tried reinstalling Grub to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to create a windows bootable pendrive to fix your windows MBR. Go on the microsoft website and find an ISO file for your windows version, or use the pendrive/DVD that came with your windows install. Reinstalling GRUB won't help.