# How to boot into Windows from live Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

I used to dual boot Linux and Windows 10, but then I deleted the partition that contains Linux and Grub, and when rebooting my computer I was faced with the grub rescue prompt.

Now I have booted into a live Ubuntu USB stick and backed up my important data, but I'm unsure what to do next. How can I fix it so I can boot back into Windows normally again? Is it possible to reinstall Grub?

Comment: If you installed in UEFI boot mode, then you just need to boot Windows directly from UEFI one time boot key, same key you used to boot live installer, often f12 or f10. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI mode since release of Windows 8 in 2012. And in UEFI change boot order.  If upgrade from an old BIOS install of Windows 7, you probably have BIOS, and need to use your Windows repair flash drive and its repair console to run fixMBR command and maybe other Windows repairs.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613778/deleted-unix-and-grub-partitions-cant-boot-into-windows-anymore

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean by UEFI boot mode. I booted into the USB stick by changing the boot order in the BIOS. Simply booting from my SSD takes me to the Grub rescue prompt. I "fixed" the problem by simply reinstalling Ubuntu, but I'll eventually have to figure out how to get rid of it without running into the same problem.

Comment: Shows Ubuntu live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI When booting live installer, you should get two boot options if system newer than 2012.  One clearly UEFI and on that will be BIOS but will not specifically say that. Windows also has two boot options.